# Extracting part of a GeoTIFF file by geographic coordinates in R

Tags: r, geotiff

I have a Natural Earth (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) map in GeoTIFF format, from which I want to extract a part by using geographic coordinates which define a polygon of interest. I then would like to save the resultant smaller map, also in GeoTIFF format.

How can this be done with R?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

**EDIT:** I got it done easily with the simple code below:

```
options(warn=-1)
library(raster)
        
df <- read.csv(file="Brasil.csv")
max.lat <- ceiling(max(df$Latitude))
min.lat <- floor(min(df$Latitude))
max.lon <- ceiling(max(df$Longitude))
min.lon <- floor(min(df$Longitude))
geographic.range <- extent(x = c(min.lon, max.lon, min.lat, max.lat))

x <- raster("NE1_50M_SR_W.tif")
x.crop <- crop(x, geographic.range)
writeRaster(x.crop, filename="Brasi.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

But the extracted image appears in shades of grey instead of in colour! What happened to the colours?

[image: Natural Earth full image]
[image: Extracted image]

Comment: see `terra::rast` for reading in first map, `terra::vect` for geo-coords of polygon of interest, `terra::crop` for smaller map, writing to file .tif in same call.